# We detected that the Chromium Renderer process just crashed Cypress CI error

Tags: cypress

I get this error at random times when I run my Cypress test scripts on Azure CI server.

```
We detected that the Chromium Renderer process just crashed.

This is the equivalent to seeing the 'sad face' when Chrome dies.

This can happen for a number of different reasons:

- You wrote an endless loop and you must fix your own code
- You are running Docker (there is an easy fix for this: see link below)
- You are running lots of tests on a memory intense application
- You are running in a memory starved VM environment
- There are problems with your GPU / GPU drivers
- There are browser bugs in Chromium
```

I am using cypress 11.2.0. I tried adding the option ***--browser chrome*** to the ***cypress run*** command, but it makes the tests fail many assertions unexpectedly. Any ideas on how to solve this?